# Howto add Ext.Net.ColumnModel to an existing Ext.Net.GridPanel programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ext.net

I try to create a GridPanel programmatically using a LinqDataSource as shown in the examples.

So far I can see my empty GridPanel without any data inside cause my GridPanel is missing the ColumnModel used to show the data.

As I can't find the right method to add the ColumnModel to the GridPanel I need to ask you.

My Code which is used to create my GridPanel and everything is underneath.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace IntraNET_Prototype
{
    public partial class MitarbeiterUndTelefonliste : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public LinqDataSource MitarbeiterDataSource = new LinqDataSource();
        public Ext.Net.GridPanel MitarbeiterGridPanel = new Ext.Net.GridPanel();
        public Ext.Net.Store MitarbeiterStore = new Ext.Net.Store();
        public Ext.Net.JsonReader MitarbeiterJSONReader = new Ext.Net.JsonReader();
        public Ext.Net.ColumnModel MitarbeiterColumnModel = new Ext.Net.ColumnModel();

        public MitarbeiterUndTelefonliste()
        {
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MitarbeiterDataSource.ID = "MitarbeiterDataSource";
            MitarbeiterDataSource.ContextTypeName = "MitarbeiterlisteEntities";
            MitarbeiterDataSource.TableName = "Mitarbeiterliste";

            MitarbeiterGridPanel.ID = "MitarbeiterGridPanel";
            MitarbeiterGridPanel.Title = "MitarbeiterListe";
            MitarbeiterGridPanel.AutoWidth = true;
            MitarbeiterGridPanel.Frame = true;
            MitarbeiterGridPanel.Height = 570;

            MitarbeiterStore.ID = "MitarbeiterStore";
            MitarbeiterStore.DataSource = MitarbeiterDataSource;

            MitarbeiterColumnModel.ID = "MitarbeiterColumnModel";

            MitarbeiterColumnModel.Columns.Add(new Ext.Net.Column() { DataIndex = "primaerschluessel", Header = "Index", Width = 50 });

            MitarbeiterJSONReader.Fields.Add(new Ext.Net.RecordField() { Name = "primaerschluessel" });

            MitarbeiterGridPanel.Store.Add(MitarbeiterStore);

            this.Form.Controls.Add(MitarbeiterGridPanel);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help! I appreciate any suggestions, critics and any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign some column model to the grid. Because it's read-only property.

You have to use MitarbeiterGridPanel.ColumnModel.Columns.Add() instead of MitarbeiterColumnModel.Columns.Add()

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's the key! But just for my understanding, isn't that a bit weird to go this way instead of adding a column model as you have to do vice-versa within the .aspx design?!

Comment: It's made because Ext.NET and ExtJS don't give any customization of ColumnModel. They give you custom columns but not custom ColumnModel. And in my experience it's never caused a problem.